# How to store and use php that's in a database field - halfway works

Tags: php, database, include

I'm having some trouble getting the php stored in a field to work properly.

I was able to do this once, creating a VARCHAR field `Modfiers` and using `eval()`. It works perfectly, reading the variables and using them in the php.

**However**, I have been unable to make this work for my `Content` field. It was TEXT but I changed it to VARCHAR, changed `echo` to `eval()`, but it still isn't working.

There are only two differences between them. One has HTML where the other is just variables, and the `Content` one uses an `include()` statement.

I've tried it with and without `<?php ?>` (thinking `eval()` may pick up on it). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered using a template engine? (I like Twig, personally, but there are many outthere, Smarty, Mustache, Dwoo, ecc.) That would avoid you using the dreaded eval() (which is more often than not a wrong choice)

Comment: First of all: _please_ try to avoid using `eval`. But, since that won't answer your question: does your content START with HTML? If so, you need to close your PHP tags in the eval: `eval('?>' . $content . '<?php');`

Comment: @ColinMorelli I'd be happy to use something else if possible - `eval()` was just the answer I found to be able to parse code from database fields. The Content does start with HTML, it's everything that goes into the `.content` div.

Comment: There are currently 2 Content fields that use `include()`, they are both surrounded by HTML. Because what they are including have quite a bit of code, this helps me keep it neat/be able to bring in segments as needed. I could have swore this worked with echo before but I could be mistaken.